# If statement in Mysql Select query umer

Tags: php, mysql

I want to filter mysql query with a post. if i get a special value in post then filter it and if it get value 'ALL' in post then show all value don't filter. i tried like this. it works but i want to handle it in one query.

```
           if($_POST['comp']== 'all' && $_POST['cat']== 'all'){
      return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items order by name");
    }
    if($_POST['comp']!= 'all' && $_POST['cat']!= 'all'){
      return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items where company = '$_POST[comp]' and             category = '$_POST[cat]' order by name");
    } 
    if($_POST['comp']!= 'all'){
      return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items where company = '$_POST[comp]' order by name");
    }
    if($_POST['cat']!= 'all'){
      return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items where category = '$_POST[cat]' order by name");
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: Read up on [if else elseif statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp)

Comment: My if else else if is working right but i want to do it in one query.

Comment: You will only execute one query if you use an if/else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    prepare the query like this:
        $query .= "SELECT * FROM items where 1=1"; 
        if($_POST['comp']!= 'all')
        {
          $query .= " and company = '$_POST[comp]'";            
        }
        if($_POST['cat']!= 'all')
        {
          $query .= " and category = '$_POST[cat]'";
        }
         $query .= " order by name";

return  $this->db->select($query);
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM items where  and category = '$_POST[cat]' order by name" - This query would not be valid.

Comment: @ScottHelme Thanks for your comment,I have edited the query can you check now?

Comment: Now it works. Check completely then accept it. Thank you very much Sanal K.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable(array) to store filter rule, after that check its length, implode and append to query string

Ex:

```
$posted = $_POST;
$where = array(1);//no need to check length if you initialise with this array
foreach($posted as $k=>$v){
    if($k != 'ALL')$where[] = ... //add new filter from $post
    else {
        $where = array(1);
        break;//break this loop when see 'ALL' option
    }
}
$where = implode(' and ',$where); //append this to query string
```

Comment: Yes you got my point but can u write down complete select query so that i can understand it better?

Comment: If you have more rule( may be default rules), you should add to $where array. And only append to main query string ex: `$sql = 'select * from my_table '.$where`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to execute one query, simply change it to if/else statements:

```
if($_POST['comp']== 'all' && $_POST['cat']== 'all'){
    return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items order by name");
}else if($_POST['comp']!= 'all' && $_POST['cat']!= 'all'){
    return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items where company = '$_POST[comp]' and category = '$_POST[cat]' order by name");
}else if($_POST['comp']!= 'all'){
    return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items where company = '$_POST[comp]' order by name");
}else if($_POST['cat']!= 'all'){
    return  $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM items where category = '$_POST[cat]' order by name");
}
```

This will now only ever execute 1 SQL query instead of all queries that match the filters.

Comment: This is what I expected. SQL experts can confirm if its possible to use a variable to achieve this in one go. I am kin to learn also.

Comment: When you say "one go", what do you mean? Only 1 SQL query will ever be executed in the code I provided. Do you mean you just want to do it with less code, by *defining* less queries?

Comment: Yes we dnt want to use one query for one post we just want to check all $_post in one query. read the answer 1 StupidDev is very close to my method.